# Difference between copy /b and cat - windows refuses to execute file (self extracting archive)

Tags: windows, bash, cat

I'm working on a script to package up an installer into a self extracting archive. Initially I was working on batch script using

```
copy /b .\7zSD.sfx + .\config.txt + .\installer.7z .\installer.exe
```

and the self extracting archive functioned as expected.

As the developers are working in a cygwin environment I tried converting to a bash script for this particular part using

```
cat 7zSD.sfx config.txt installer.7z > installer.exe
```

The file is properly created and can be extracted using for example winrar, yet executing results in the attached windows error:

[image: Windows Error]

Are there differences that I should be aware of or does somebody know of the right way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

While I did unsuccessfully try yesterday to change the permissions via the *windows file properties*, I did not try changing the permissions with `chmod`.

Checking the permissions using `ls -l installer.exe` revealed them as only having read/write permissions for *users* and *groups*.
My solution was to do a

```
chmod 770 installer.exe
```

to get this working.